# Allow mysql connection from anywhere

Tags: mysql

I need to use mysql with my C# app. If I want to share my app, the connection can come from any IP Address. How do I allow everyone no matter where it's used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest here, it's not a good practice to accept request from any IP.

Answer for your question is:

`GRANT <set of privileges> on <schema>.<table/*> TO <user>@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <password>` it can allow to receive connections through specific  from any source.

Comment: do add grant for user@'localhost' to allow it from localhost as well